# Devise routing error on Forgot password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I click on `<%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %>`

It takes me to

http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/password/new

with the routing error

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Devise/passwords#new

Showing app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"password", :id=>:user}
```

**Edit:**

**new.html.erb Error on this line**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

**Passwords_controller.rb**

```
class Devise::PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  #prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

  access_control do
      allow all
  end

  # GET /resource/password/new
  def new
    build_resource({})
    render_with_scope :new
  end

  # POST /resource/password
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])

    if successful_and_sane?(resource)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
    render_with_scope :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource/password
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[resource_name])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :updated) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
    end
  end

  protected

    # The path used after sending reset password instructions
    def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing this line in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
```

If this doesn't help you then I recommend to follow this two railscasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

You will find all necessary information there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still gives the same routing error.No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"password", :id=>:user}

Comment: are you sure that resource_name is not nil? Can you show me the wrong line of app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb and the controller action responsible for rendering of this view?

Comment: Changed added the view and controller

Comment: Do you have "devise_for :users" in your routes,rb?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue. I was missing the `recoverable` model in my User model:

```
class User
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :validatable,
         :recoverable
end
```

Once I added `:recoverable` I saw the missing password routes when I ran `rake routes`:

```
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                   devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                  devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
```